# DocuSign API account creation with multiple tenants

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docusignapi

If I were to create a multi-tenant application I am trying to figure out how many accounts would need to be created on the DocuSign end.

As a DocuSign developer I have a single sandbox account. I am assuming if my app went to production I would have a single production account.

Can someone help me understand how DocuSign would manage the structure below. Would a DocuSign account need to be made per tenant, per administrator, or per customer?

Tenant 1 (companyA.myapp.com)
     Administrator 1 (someone who will upload documents that need to be signed) - will have a login to the Tenant 1 app
     Customer 1 (someone who will sign the documents) - will have a login to the Tenant 1 app

Tenant 2 (companyB.myapp.com)
     Administrator 1 (someone who will upload documents that need to be signed) - will have a login to the Tenant 1 app
     Customer 1 (someone who will sign the documents) - will have a login to the Tenant 1 app

I am thinking about billing here. Would I need a DocuSign developer account per tenant or can I handle this all under a single DocuSign account.

Will the administrators and customers of the tenant app all need to create their own personal DocuSign accounts at some point? If so will everything that happens still be stored under my developer account?

It would be ideal if the mappings we're exact:

For example it would be great if my developer account would let me add multiple apps to it. 1 per tenant. Then within each app I would be able to list all of the administrator accounts where each administrators uploaded documents would be stored. Then finally for the customers I am not sure if I would need to do anything if they are just signing the docs.

Something like this:

Tenant 1
     Administrator 1
          Uploaded docs for signing
     Administrator 2
          Uploaded docs for signing

Tenant 2
     Administrator 1
          Uploaded docs for signing
     Administrator 2
          Uploaded docs for signing

I would like to know how all of this would get broken out in the DocuSign world under a single developer account.

Answer (score 2):

we call "tenants" accounts. Your app is developed under your personal account, but when it's ready to be used - it can be used with any account. You can add more users to your account if you want to test different scenarios. Sandbox accounts are free even if you add as many users as you want.